「色んな意味を含む言葉」「色んな意味が含まれた言葉」
「色んな意味を含んでいて、説明しにくい言葉です」と言いたいのですが、検索数は思ったより少ないようだから、自然な言い方なのか不安です。

色んな意味を含んでいる言葉
色んな意味を含んだ言葉
色んな意味を含む言葉
色んな意味が含まれた言葉
色んな意味が含まれている言葉
色んな意味が含まれる言葉

どちらが自然に聞こえますか？

例とし挙げてくれた６つの文は、間違いの無い自然な文です。意味やニュアンスも特に違いが無いので、どれを使っても良いと思います。
